# how to specify utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation to a model column in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am using RoR 4.2.1 and mysql. I want to create a table which has a column 'description' which need to support emoji. So I want to specify collation for the column in the migration file. I have used the following code

```
t.text :description, :collate => "utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
```

But it creates a model which has description column, having collation 'utf8_unicode_ci'. How can I create a column having collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci. I don't want to execute an alter query after creating table.

Thank you.

Comment: Did anyone end up finding a solution for this?